# Custom log level is overwritten by default log level with robotframework

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I have created a custom log level as 'PASS' with levelnum as 42 in python3.x,
when using this newly created log level in robot framework,instead of log level as 'PASS' the log message was marked with 'ERROR' in the logs.

Is there any issue with using custom log level of python with robot framework.

Comment: I never heard about "custom loglevel". Can you share how you did this, or document reference? Thanks.

Comment: Using logging module  and method addLevelName available in python we can create our own logging levels.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].